# File doesn't exist when trying to run as sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

Running `sudo /usr/local/sbin/sudo_nginx_test` returns the following error: `sudo: /usr/local/sbin/sudo_nginx_test: command not found`

`/usr/local/sbin/sudo_nginx_test` definitely exists and I can nano the file to see my command `nginx -t`

I am running an ec2 instance on AWS.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you type "sudo su" to switch to root and then type "/usr/local/sbin/sudo_nginx_test" ?

Comment: Does your file contain a hashbang line (e.g. #!/bin/bash), and if so, is the shell or other program on that line actually available at the given path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ls -l /usr/local/sbin/sudo_nginx_test`. I would bet that it doesn’t have the needed execution permissions `x`. Correct that with

```
chmod a+x /usr/local/sbin/sudo_nginx_test
```

Comment: Thank you, it didn't have execution permissions.